# What's wrong with this piece of sql query where i am trying to add multiple record in a table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
INSERT ALL
INTO Emp(EmpID,EmpName,Loc,DESIGNATION,DeptID,Sal,HireDate,MgrID)
VALUES
(102,'Matt','Mumbai','Developer',1022,80000,'10-APR-1991',NULL),
(103,'Jhon','Banglore','Supervisor',1011,75000,'26-MAR-1986',102),
(104,'David','Hyderbad','Clerk',1033,40000,103),
(105,'Paul','Banglore','Clerk',1011,35000,103),
(106,'Jones','Mumbai','Developer',1022,85000,NULL)
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

> **ERROR at line 4: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword**

I am using Oracle 11g

Comment: If you are inserting into a single table, why are you using an `INSERT ALL` statement to begin with? That is to insert into more than one table with a single statement.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify `INTO` part for each `VALUES`:

```
INSERT ALL
 INTO Emp(EmpID,EmpName,Loc,DESIGNATION,DeptID,Sal,HireDate,MgrID) 
   VALUES (102,'Matt','Mumbai','Developer',1022,80000,'10-APR-1991',NULL)
 INTO Emp(EmpID,EmpName,Loc,DESIGNATION,DeptID,Sal,HireDate,MgrID) 
   VALUES (103,'Jhon','Banglore','Supervisor',1011,75000,'26-MAR-1986',102)
 INTO Emp(EmpID,EmpName,Loc,DESIGNATION,DeptID,Sal,HireDate,MgrID) 
   VALUES (104,'David','Hyderbad','Clerk',1033,40000,SYSDATE,103) 
 INTO Emp(EmpID,EmpName,Loc,DESIGNATION,DeptID,Sal,HireDate,MgrID) 
   VALUES (105,'Paul','Banglore','Clerk',1011,35000,SYSDATE,103)
 INTO Emp(EmpID,EmpName,Loc,DESIGNATION,DeptID,Sal,HireDate,MgrID) 
   VALUES  (106,'Jones','Mumbai','Developer',1022,85000,SYSDATE,NULL) 
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
-- Rows 3-5 does not have HireDate so I inserted SYSDATE
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=db069feb59b8e9b9312e4594b45707b6)**

Answer (score 2):

Oracle doesn't allow multiple row inserts with `values`.  I think the simplest method is `select . . . union all`:

```
INSERT INTO Emp(EmpID,EmpName,Loc,DESIGNATION,DeptID,Sal,HireDate,MgrID)
    SELECT 102,'Matt','Mumbai','Developer',1022,80000,'10-APR-1991',NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 103,'Jhon','Banglore','Supervisor',1011,75000,'26-MAR-1986',102 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 104,'David','Hyderbad','Clerk',1033,40000,103 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 105,'Paul','Banglore','Clerk',1011,35000,103 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 106,'Jones','Mumbai','Developer',1022,85000,NULL FROM DUAL ;
```